# Multiple Page forms and Database Logic?

Tags: codeigniter

Im building an application where a user will need to go through a multiple page form which will have 30+ fields of data, including image uploads.

What im wondering is what the best way of setting up my database will be? Do I split the data up over multiple tables, or would it be better to put all the data into one table?

Im not sure, I can see pros and cons to both... Anyone have any input on the matter?

Im looking at building the app with codeigniter.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What's the data? A single table might have thirty columns, or you might need ten different tables with three columns each. It's not the sheer amount of data that's significant, but rather the nature of the data and the relationships between the fields.

I'm guessing that the answer will involve multiple tables, but without more information, it's just a guess.